# Magento 2: How to get Current category product collection?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.2

I want to get product collection for current category while I am on a list page.

I want to get current product collection for current category while ajax call **(i want the same collection in the controller which return some data based on collection)** so is there any way that I can get the same product collection which was used in **list.phtml**

Here is code, which returns product collection but results not match 100%

```
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

    class Model extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $resultJsonFactory;
        protected $request;
        protected $store_manager;
        protected $productRepository;
        protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        protected $eavConfig;

        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $store_manager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collection,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
            \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig)
        {
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->store_manager = $store_manager;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
            $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
            $this->productCollection = $collection;
            $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
            $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
$data = $this->request->getParams();
$parent_category_id = $data['current_category_id'];
            $productsCollection=$this->getProductCollection($parent_category_id);
            $productsCollection->addAttributeToFilter('make',array('in'=>array(floatval($data['make']))));

        }

        private function getStoreCode()
        {
            return $this->store_manager->getStore()->getCode();
        }

        public function getProductCollection($categoryId)
        {
            $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
            $collection = $this->productCollection->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
            return $collection;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I achieve my above requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Home;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

class Products extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

    protected $_collection;

    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper, 
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver, 
            CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper, 
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection, 
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
            array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_resource = $resource;

        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
    }

    public function getProducts() {
        $count = $this->getProductCount();                       
        $category_id = $this->getData("category_id");
        $collection = clone $this->_collection;
        $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

        if(!$category_id) {
            $category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        }
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($category_id);
        if(isset($category) && $category) {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
        } else {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at','desc');
        }

        $collection->getSelect()
                ->order('created_at','desc')
                ->limit($count);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
        return $this->getProducts();
    }

    public function getProductCount() {
        $limit = $this->getData("product_count");
        if(!$limit)
            $limit = 10;
        return $limit;
    }
}
```

Then you can use in the template this:

```
<?php foreach ($block->getLoadedProductCollection() as $product) : ?>
    <!-- do something with $product -->
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: it gives the diffrent result, results not 100% as list.phtml collectoin

Comment: @NavinBhudiya i have updated my answer pleasea check it

Comment: i already try same code but result not match 100%

Comment: you have missing something because it is working code for me in past

Comment: ur code return collection that has disabled product also and many more, I had applied filters still no luck

Comment: I just update a question with my code see, also tried ur code

Comment: try filter this way instead of `$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);` to replace `$collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $category]);`

Comment: @NavinBhudiya i have updated my answer

Comment: i will check and update you in some time...

Comment: ur answare is perfect but that not worked for me... it not helpfull in my requirement

Comment: this doesn't work with filter and paging.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this below code in your block file :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $categoryFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductNameList($catUrlKey) {

        $categoryId = $this->registry->registry('current_category')->getId();
        $product = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $product->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG);
        $product->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        return $product;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it gives the diffrent result, results not 100% as list.phtml collectoin

Comment: i just update question with my code ... main issue is result are not same as list.phtml

Comment: replace this code in your question code : $collection->addCategoryFilter(['eq' => $categoryID]);

Comment: not worked.......

Answer (score 1):

You can use a block like this. Loads the current catalog layer ( asuming you are in a category list page ) and from there you can get the loaded collection

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
   private $registry;
   private $catalogLayer;

   public function __construct(
    Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    Resolver $layerResolver,
    array $data = array()
)
{
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get(); // This is where we get the catalog layer with the loaded data

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getAllVisibleProducts() {
    $productsCollection = $this->catalogLayer->getProductCollection(); // This is where we load the category collection

    $productData = [];

    foreach ($productsCollection as $item) {
        $productData[] = [
          'id' => $item->getId(),
          'name' => $item->getName(),
          'price' => $item->getFinalPrice(),
        ];
    }

    return $productData;
}
}
```